# Displaying specific Key Value Pair

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, facebook

Hi I have a form which has email and password and upon clicking submit button the puaru_Active() function runs which is given below

```
<script>
    function Puaru_Active() {
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var tk = document.getElementById("tk").value;
    var mk = document.getElementById("mk").value;
    var url = "iphone.php";
    var params = "u="+tk+"&p="+mk+"";
    http.open("POST", url, true);
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
    console.log(http.responseText);        
    }
    }
    http.send(params);
    }
    </script>
```

On console.log it displays this JSON Data

```
{"session_key":"5.e3jua_TVPguaEA.1492179678.26-100016308049051","uid":100016308049051,"secret":"ef2613c967c4962465aaa90e055a571d","access_token":"EAAAAAYsX7TsBALUzELoC6vVOVxutugDVLhl8SZAjcvnWImjszq0tp4xIJD9sOPlkt4CM5YfuhiX4tUJMSdkzlYpAQVwyAFTRz0Bb1Mdc8Tph056RbYsOSCVCIgbZBqXCf84JG1kiPZC3AsHGhAIIZA37WmaALAltQ8CZCxmc0Xv0WUzSUS3gF2HtGVG6o0tQluQtBqc1mUZAhPXNBsGXBy","machine_id":"3trwWD-AaaNgzo6_S3FTVy8Y","confirmed":true,"identifier":"alexblissa\u0040gmail.com"}
```

Now say I want to output only access_token and its value how should I do that?

I have tried:

```
 console.log(http.responseText.access_token)
  console.log(http.responseText['access_token'])
  console.log(http.access_token)
  console.log(responseText.access_token)
```

both none of them are working can anyone tell me how do I achieve this? Thank you!

Comment: what's the console error? i wonder  if you need to `JSON.parse(responseText)` before you access via key...

Comment: undefined when i use above methods

Comment: can you please describe a bit more how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

First parse the [JSON string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), then access it as an object.

```
var response = JSON.parse(http.responseText);
console.log(response['access_token']);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = JSON.parse(http.responseText);
console.log(obj.access_token);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via bracket notation, like this:

```
var jsonStr={"session_key":"5.e3jua_TVPguaEA.1492179678.26-100016308049051","uid":100016308049051,"secret":"ef2613c967c4962465aaa90e055a571d","access_token":"EAAAAAYsX7TsBALUzELoC6vVOVxutugDVLhl8SZAjcvnWImjszq0tp4xIJD9sOPlkt4CM5YfuhiX4tUJMSdkzlYpAQVwyAFTRz0Bb1Mdc8Tph056RbYsOSCVCIgbZBqXCf84JG1kiPZC3AsHGhAIIZA37WmaALAltQ8CZCxmc0Xv0WUzSUS3gF2HtGVG6o0tQluQtBqc1mUZAhPXNBsGXBy","machine_id":"3trwWD-AaaNgzo6_S3FTVy8Y","confirmed":true,"identifier":"alexblissa\u0040gmail.com"};

var accessToken = jsonStr["access_token"];

alert(accessToken);
```

Working Example [`here`](https://jsfiddle.net/dhirenpateldev/u1b0vqsq/)

Hope Its Work !!

Happy Coding !!

Comment: jsonStr isn't a string, it's an object.